# Interpolação de variável em shell script que retorna a saída de uma função

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Isolei um problema de um script maior que estou produzindo. Basicamente eu tenho uma função que retorna a data e hora atual em um formato específico. Preciso que cada vez que a variável `data_hora` seja imprimida na tela, seus valores sejam atualizados a partir do retorno da execução dessa função.

---

ATUALIZAÇÃO

[28/12/2015]

Importante ressaltar que a variável deve ser interpolada numa string. No caso,
toda vez que imprimirmos `obter_data` a saída deverá ser a data atualizada.

Este código é utilizado em um script que é carregado somente uma vez (ele compõe meus .dotfiles). Toda vez que essa variável é interpolada em uma string ela tem voltado a data/hora em que o fonte do script foi carregado e não a hora atual.

---

Para exemplificar, imprimimos a variável 3x com intervalos de 1 segundo.

A saída desejada é como segue abaixo:

[27/12/2015 22:26:00]

[27/12/2015 22:26:01]

[27/12/2015 22:26:02]

Contudo, o código de exemplo abaixo produz a saída a seguir:

[27/12/2015 22:26:00]

[27/12/2015 22:26:00]

[27/12/2015 22:26:00]

Abaixo o código fonte:

```
function data_hora_atual {
    echo `date +"[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S]"`
}

obter_data=$(data_hora_atual)

data_hora=$(echo "${obter_data}")

echo ${data_hora}

sleep 1

echo ${data_hora}

sleep 1

echo ${data_hora}
```

Answer (score 2):

A sua função `data_hora_atual` está retornado um `echo` e não um comando em si, deste forma as duas variáveis `$obter_data` e `$data_hora` estava guardando a saída do `echo` e não do comando `date`.

Bom, eu fiz uma adulteração no seu script e funcionou:

```
#!/bin/bash

function data_hora_atual {
    date +"[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S]"
}

data_hora_atual 

sleep 1

data_hora_atual 

sleep 1

data_hora_atual
```

Comment: Dener, preciso que a variável seja interpolada dentro de um string. Não deixei especificado na pergunta, vou atualizá-la.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

function data_hora_atual {
    date +"[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S]"
}

clear # limpa tela

obter_data=data_hora_atual # instancia da função

data_hora=${obter_data} # interpolação da instancia

data_hora_atual # 1° print da função

sleep 1

${obter_data} # 2° print da instancia

sleep 1

${data_hora} # 3° print da interpolação
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o que quer basta colocar o conteúdo da string que deseja que seja executado dentro de acentos graves `

```
#!/bin/bash
print_date="date +[%d/%m/%Y0\x20%H:%M:%S]" # \x20 evita problemas de quebra de lista de argumentos

echo `${print_date}`

sleep 1

echo `${print_date}`

sleep 1

echo `${print_date}`
```

Os acentos graves irão executar a instrução contida dentro e retornar a saída que no caso é o retorno de ***date***.
Não pode ser invertido como no seu exemplo, pois `obter_data=$(data_hora_atual)` fará com que *obter_data* receba um valor que não se altera a menos que seja executado novamente, o que não acontece no exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez

```
function data_hora_atual {
    echo `date +"[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S]"`
}

obter_data=$(data_hora_atual)

data_hora=$(echo "${obter_data}")

echo ${data_hora}

sleep 1

obter_data=$(data_hora_atual)

data_hora=$(echo "${obter_data}")

echo ${data_hora}

sleep 1

obter_data=$(data_hora_atual)

data_hora=$(echo "${obter_data}")

echo ${data_hora}
```